# Why don't the elements line up in this html?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a select box element from scratch with a custom theme. When I have `overflow:hidden;` on line 59 in my css the elements don't line up the way I would expect. However, when I remove that line it does line up the way I would expect but the text will overflow. It does seem to work in chrome but not firefox.

Working:

[image: Working]

Not Working:

[image: Not Working]

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/nd7Hn/

Why does that happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please show a screenshot of what it is supposed to look like. Removing line 59 makes no visible difference

Comment: @feitla It does work the way I expected in chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this style:

```
.editor-controls>* {vertical-align:top}
```

Otherwise elements will try to align to their baseline, which may produce unexpected results.

Comment: I was about the suggest the exact same thing :)

Comment: @IanClark More people need to know about `vertical-align` - I use it all the time, and yet it seems hardly anyone else knows about it...